# GoogleAPIクライアントライブラリを使用して認証時に手にしたアクセストークンでCredentialを作成したい

Tags: google-api

GoogleのOAuth認証を行うために、GoogleAPIクライアントライブラリを使用して、サーブレットのヘルパークラスを使用して、
サーブレット認証フローをコーディングしました。
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2
上記を参考にServletSampleクラスとServletCallbackSampleを用意し、
Googleのアクセス許可画面が表示され、アクセス許可を選択するとServletCallbackSampleの
onSuccess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Credential credential)が実行されることは確認できました。
これにより、認証できたという認識です。
onSuccessの引数から、認証コード、アクセストークン、リフレッシュトークンがとれていることを確認できました。
req.getParameter("code");
credential.getAccessToken()
credential.getRefreshToken()

次にGoogleAPIを実行したいと思うのですが、以下を見ますと、
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2
アクセストークンがある場合は次の方法でリクエストを行うことが可能です

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Plus plus = new Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                             GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                             credential)
    .setApplicationName("Google-PlusSample/1.0")
    .build();
```

とあります。
ここで伺いたいのですが、アクセストークンさえ保存しておけば（たとえばデータベースで管理したり）
アクセストークンの期限内であればCredentialを作成し、APIが実行できる認識でいるのですが問題ないでしょうか？
また、GoogleCredentialは公式のドキュメントを見ますとDeprecated非推奨とあるのですが、
アクセストークンからcredentialを取得する方法はありますでしょうか？